# How to fix error when computing proportions with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have got the following dataset:

```
a<-data_frame(gender= c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
              school= c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
             year=c(2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012),
              numberofstudents=c(3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2))
```

And I wanted to get a proportion of males for each school per year. So, result should look like

```
data_frame(maleprop= c(1,0,0.66,0.5),
              school= c(2,2,3,3),
              year=c(2011,2012,2011,2012),
              )
```

I tried this code, unfortunately I have got an Error Column `maleprop` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3.

```
final <- a %>%
  group_by(school,year) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    school<-mean(school),
    year<-mean(year),
    maleprop <-(sum(gender==1))/(numberofstudents))
```

How avoid this problem and get the right results?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a few lines too many. This should do it:

```
final <- a %>%
  group_by(school,year) %>%
  summarize(maleprop = sum(gender)/mean(numberofstudents))
```